# Expected Value and Variance for a Probability Function

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

The annual number of claims on a given policy follows a distribution whose probability function is:

P(K=k) = $(\frac{D}{1+D})^k$ * ($\frac{1}{1+D})$

1) Your company has sold 300 policies in total

2) 200 policies have D = 2, and 100 policies have D = 5

What are the expected number of claims for the D = 2 policies as a group? D = 5?

What are the variances for each?

I am not sure how to start with this one. I don't know what the D's mean so this question isn't easily interpreted for me. I plugged in D = 2 and k = 200 into the equation and got a really low number.

EDIT: I have that this is discrete and the expected value of a discrete random variable X is $\sum$xf(x). But what is x and how do I obtain the probability for D = 2? What goes into the function? There are two possibilities: D = 2 or 5. Shouldn't these two probabilities add up to 1?

Comment: What would be the expected number of claims on one policy?

Comment: I would think k = 1 would go into the equation but no idea what D would be

Comment: Hint, by definition, the expected value of a discrete random variable $X$ is $\sum xf(x).$

Comment: @SeanRoberson So for D = 2, would x be 200?

Comment: @SeanRoberson There are two possibilities, D = 2 or D = 5 so shouldn't the sum of the two probabilities equal 1?

Comment: For starters, what does the random variable $K$ represent here? Edit your question to include all details from the question, perhaps verbatim. I'm not convinced this is a probability mass function.

Comment: @SeanRoberson It doesn't say. I gave all the known details. It really is unclear.

Comment: $K$ is the number of claims on a given policy. You have $EK = \sum_k k p[K=k]$.

Comment: @copper.hat So for D = 2 would the expected value be 200 multiplied by the function with D = 2 and k = 200 as the inputs? That's a really low number so I am assuming that's incorrect.

Comment: No. You need to read about computing the expected value, which is, in this case, $0 \cdot (\text{probability that }K=0) + 1 \cdot (\text{probability that }K=1)+2 \cdot (\text{probability that }K=2)+\cdots$. I added a partial answer below, but you need to do some review first.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay, thank you. I don't have my statistics textbook on me, but I will look online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the geometric distribution with $p={1 \over 1+D}$. The
Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) has many relevant details.

First, let us find the formulae for one claim, then for $m$ claims
and finally the computations.

---

For one claim:

For general $D$, we have
$\overline{K}=EK = \sum_{i=0}^\infty i \cdot p[K=i] = \sum_{i=0}^\infty i ({D \over 1+D})^i {1 \over 1+D } = D$.

We have $\operatorname{var} K = E(K-\overline{K})^2 = E K^2 - (E K)^2$, and
$E K^2 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty i^2 ({D \over 1+D})^i {1 \over 1+D } = D(1+2D)$, and
so $\operatorname{var} K = D(1+D)$.

---

For $m$ policies:

Hence, for general $D$, if we have $m$ policies, then
 $E[\sum_i K_i] = m \overline{K} = m D$.

The variance of $m$ policies is slightly more complicated, to make life simple, I am assuming that the claims for each policy are independent. In particular, this means
that for $i \neq j$, we have $E[K_i K_j] = (E K_i )(E K_j)$.

Then the computation is as follows 
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{var} (\sum_i K_i) &=& E(\sum_i (K_i - \overline{K}_i))^2 \\
&=& = E(\sum_i K_i)^2 - (E[\sum_i K_i])^2 \\
&=& E [ (\sum_i K_i) (\sum_j K_j) ]  - m^2 \overline{K}^2 \\
&=& \sum_i \sum_j E [K_i K_j] - m^2 \overline{K}^2 \\
&=& \sum_i E [K_i^2] + \sum_i \sum_{j \neq i} E [K_i K_j] - m^2 \overline{K}^2 \\
&=& m E [K^2]   + \sum_i \sum_{j \neq i} E [K_i] E[ K_j] - m^2 \overline{K}^2 \\
&=& m E [K^2]  + (m^2-m) \overline{K}^2 - m^2 \overline{K}^2 \\
&=& m \operatorname{var} K \\
&=& m D (1+D)
\end{eqnarray}

---

Finally, the computations:

So, for $D=2$, $m=200$, we have $E[\sum_i K_i] = 200 \cdot 2 = 400$ and
$\operatorname{var} (\sum_i K_i) = 200 \cdot 2 (1+2) = 1200$.

So, for $D=5$, $m=100$, we have $E[\sum_i K_i] = 100 \cdot 5 = 500$ and
$\operatorname{var} (\sum_i K_i) = 100 \cdot 5 (1+5) = 3000$.

---

Regarding you question about confidence intervals:

I am not sure how you want to model this one. One way is to have three sets of independent
variables; $X_k$ (whose statistics correspond to $D=2$), $Y_k$ (whose statistics correspond to $D=5$) and a choice variable $\sigma_k$ that takes the value $1$
with probability $p={2 \over 3}$ (since two thirds of the claims
are of type $D=2$) and value $0$ otherwise.

Then we model each (of many) claims as 
$Z_k = \sigma_k X_k + (1-\sigma_k) Y_k$.

A quick computation shows
$E Z_k = p E X_k + (1-p)E Y_k$ and
$E Z_k^2 = p E X_k^2 + (1-p)E Y_k^2$.

Calculating shows $E Z_k = {2 \over 3} 2 + {1 \over 3} 5 = 3$,
$E Z_k^2 = {2 \over 3} 2\cdot 5 + {1 \over 3} 5 \cdot 11 = 25$, and
so $\operatorname{var} Z_k = 16$ (and hence $\sigma_{Z_k} = 4$).

Then we model ${ {1 \over n} \sum_{k=0}^n Z_k - EZ_k \over { \sigma_{Z_k} \over \sqrt{n}  } }$ as ${\cal N} (0,1)$.

The $95 \%$ bounds correspond to $EZ_k \pm 1.96  {\sigma_{Z_k} \over \sqrt{n}  }$, or roughly $(2.55,3.45)$.

Comment: Ah okay, and for the second part, it'd just be mD = 100 * 5 = 500.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okay, I will try to find how the variances would be calculated and get back to you sometime later today.

Comment: Also, I am a little iffy on your third to last line where you take the sum from 0 to infinity. Does it equal D because those are all the possible outcomes (0 to inf)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. It is the expected value of a geometric distribution (which includes $k=0$). If you evaluate the sum over $i$ you will get the value $D$. In general, for a discreet distribution, you have $EX = \sum_k k p[X=k]$. It is an average, taking into account the varying probabilities.

Comment: I have that the variance is equal to E(x^2)-E(x)^2 = E(x^2) - 400^2. E(x^2), I'm not sure how to approach this but I'll give it a go. We have E[K1....K200] with each K=D=2. So 2^2 = 4 so it'd be 4*200=800 giving us a variance of 800-400^2. But that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to compute $EX^2 = \sum_k k^2 p[X=k]$. You **can't** set $K=2$, it makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Would that be the same as your sum in the third to last line, but with the first i being squared?

Comment: so (i^2)((D)/(1+D))^(i)(1/1+D)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46910/discussion-between-john-h-and-copper-hat).

Comment: I have revamped my answer considerably. Hopefully this clarifies. The basic point above is that the mean of the sum is the sum of the means and, if the variables are independent, then the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances. So, once you compute the underlying statistics, you know the statistics of the sum.

Comment: Thanks for putting so much time into helping me. I am going to try and compute the standard deviation and z-scores associated with a 95% confidence interval tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: Hope it helps, the standard deviation is just the square root of the variance.

Comment: If it wants the standard deviation of all 300 claims however would it be the square root of the each variance, and then summed? Or the sum of the variances, then square rooted? Or possibly neither?

Comment: It would be the square root of the variance of the 300 claims, in this case $\sqrt{1200+3000}$.

Comment: But the variance for 200 claims is different than the variance of the 100 claims. Ah okay

Comment: The variance of the sum is the sum of the variances (assuming independence, or at least uncorrelated).

Comment: Alright, I'm gonna go to bed now. Got class in the morning. If I ask you another question tomorrow, will you see it? Idk if there are notifications on this site for comments.

Comment: Well, if I get a chance I will have a look. I do have a day job :-). Good luck!

Comment: Oh okay, no rush. Just whenever you get a chance. Good night!

Comment: So my next objective is to construct a 95% confidence interval for the claim rate on the 300 policies as a group. Claim rate is defined as the number of claims divided by the number of policies. So I suppose the mean would be (400+500)/300=3. So now I need to find the claim rate at the z-scores of -1.96 and 1.96. All that is left to do is calculate the standard deviation which I'd suppose is 0 < S.D. < 3.

Comment: It wouldn't be the standard deviation that we obtained before (64.807), divided by 300, would it?

Comment: Which would give us bounds at (2.57659, 3.42341)

Comment: You should add another question for that.

Comment: Eh, people don't seem to be liking this question judging by the down votes and it being on hold. You're the only one really helping me out.

Comment: I added some notes above.

Comment: Ok, I will have a look, thanks.

Comment: That seems like it'd be more accurate being that the S.D. is an integer in your case, while mine is a crazy decimal

Comment: Well, it has been a long time since I studied statistics (35+ years), the above is more probability, so treat it with some scepticism in a statistics context.